# How to properly use a hook to create template for custom product type in a plugin such as Woocommerce?

Tags: plugin-development, themes, templates

I created my own product type for Woocommerce. But now I am looking for the solution for a frontend template.

I see in de folder templates/single-product/add-to-cart templates for Simple, grouped variable etc. How can I define a path for my own product type frontend template?

Comment: would you mind updating the question topic? Eg `how to add add to cart template for custom product type in Woocommerce` so that future audience may benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an action in the format `woocommerce_YOUR_PRODUCT_TYPE_add_to_cart` to reach the goal. Here is the example.

- The following code is for putting in `functions.php`, if you are writing a plugin. Please remember to change the callback.

eg. you have a product type called `Special`, you want to add the add-to-cart template for it.

- add the action filter `woocommerce_special_add_to_cart`
- add the action function `woocommerce_special_add_to_cart`

```
// it is better to follow the naming conventions in Woocommerce for the ease of understanding

add_action( 'woocommerce_special_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_special_add_to_cart', 30 );
function q363582_special_add_to_cart() {
   /**
     * Output the special product add to cart area.
     */
    function woocommerce_special_add_to_cart() {
        wc_get_template( 'your-own-path/special.php' ); // if you have arguments, you could use, read the the manual links of this function for reference
    }
}
```

For the path, since Woocommerce allow template customisation in theme, so your path could be something like `your-theme/single-product/add-to-cart/special.php` if you use wc_get_template() function.

The `woocommerce_special_add_to_cart` action will be called by another action `woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart` which will read the type of the product and create the respective action.

```
// usage
wc_get_template( $template_name, $args = array(), $template_path = '', $default_path = '' )
```

According to this function, you may also use your own `$template_path`, so I think this should meet your need.

For details, you may read docs:
[wc_get_template()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_template.html)

For the usage of `wc_get_template()`, you may refer to source code for examples of default product types like grouped, variation and so on:
[wc-template-functions.php](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart.html#1563-1609)