# How to direct WordPress to load custom template for custom post type

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I create a plugin that create a new product-type called exploded. 
For this product type I want create a whole new product page if the product is equal on my product-type.

I tried the {product-type}-add-to-cart filter but this is only for the button section.

Can I replace the content-single-product file is the product-type is equal?

Comment: I think this is a similar question that I have answered before. I have made an example in this question for creating custom product type template. Please refer to [Woocommerce frontend template custom product type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/363582/woocommerce-frontend-template-custom-product-type/363584#363584)

Comment: But this is only the **add_to_cart** section I want if is product-type is.... load my own template for the whole page.

Comment: I have added the suggested method and I recommend you to change the title to `how to add product template for custom product type` for better understanding to different audience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future audience sake, this notice is added.

The following answer assumed anyone have the following knowledge

- php and basic debug knowledge: how to [var_dump()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or [print_r()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)
- WordPress Core Filter and Action known as [Hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/), when and how to use them correctly
- feel comfortable modifying theme file functions.php
- for plugin-related development, please refer to [Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/)
- The examples are working for both putting in functions.php or in your plugin's file. Additional logic for your own plugin required to be added by yourself since each conditions are different.

## Method 1 (inside theme)

You may need to create your own `single-product.php` and place in **your-theme/woocommerce/single-product.php**;

- prepare 2 more files in the same folder, `content-single-exploded.php` and `content-single-other.php` and place in the same folder of `single-product.php`

If you want to control the logic in template file `single-product.php`
Inside your template file, you may do the following, this will help to choose different template files for inclusion.

Do the following in your **single-product.php**, here is a simplified version to illustrate the concept.

```
// ...
<?php

if( $product->get_type() === 'exploded' ) {
wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-exploded' );
} else {
wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-other' );
}
// ...
?>
```

## Method 2 (for both theme or plugin)

If in case you want to control template in plugin, you can use the filter `template_include` and do the checking you need.

You may put the following code into theme functions.php or your plugin and try to load a single product page.

*** It is NOT necessary to add the following code inside any action.**

```
// you can use this filter to control the template path and use the plugin template
add_filter( 'template_include', 'q363767_tweak_template' );
function q363767_tweak_template( $template ) {
    if( preg_match( '/single-product.php/', $template ) ) {
        // do the tweaking and update the path to single-product-explode.php with plugin directory
        // you may do var_dump here to see what is $template eg.
        // var_dump( $template );
        // $template = 'your-template-path';
    }

    return $template;
}
```

As the answer is for template file, this way will not work as expected:

```
function your_function() {
// not necessary to put the code here 
// XXX
// copy the above code here and run -> will NOT work
// XXX
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product','your_function');
```

Because `woocommerce_before_single_product` is not for controlling the whole template and it is not necessary.

Comment: Hi simongcc I changed the title and the question for better understanding. I am look for a replace if product-type is equal. My code is written in a plugin.

Comment: `If product-type is equal`, what do you mean? Equal to `exploded`?

Comment: Yes if the product-type is equal to exploded. Woocommerce load always the content-single-product file. I want loaf another file if the product-type is equal to exploded

Comment: The above suggested code is already doing what you would like to, it load exploded only if equal but other if not. Did you try?

Comment: I understand the code but the product-type **exploded** is a plugin. Can I add your code with a hook our action from my plugin to Woocommerce? Maybe an action for overrule the content-single-product file

Comment: I have updated the answer which solve exactly your problem.

Comment: I have this so far 

`function your_function(){

 function q363767_tweak_template( $template ) {
  global $product;
  if( $product->is_type( 'exploded' ) ) {
   $template = PLUGIN_URL . '/exploded_product/required/templates/exploded-content.php';
  }
  return $template;
 }  
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_locate_template', 'q363767_tweak_template' );
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product','your_function');`

But no template showing. If I echo the URL directly I see on the product page the link

Comment: Why you use `woocommerce_before_single_product`? Did you mentione that you want to load a whole different template? If you would like to use `woocommerce_before_single_product`, the writing is a little bit different. Let me update the answer later. Because the current solutions is load different file completely for single product.

Comment: The filter `woocommerce_before_single_product` did not help you to change the template. You just need to add the filter to your plugin without using this action. Where did you put the the code? You may try to put the code in functions.php before moving to the plugins. If it works. It is just a code migration from functions.php to your own plugin.

Comment: Yes I want load a whole different template so I can design everything for this product-type. The code above I put this in my functions.php file in my plugin direction.

Comment: You just copy the filter `template_include` code into functions.php and try.  You don't need to put into any additional action.

Comment: I have added note to your replied code why your code will not work.